# Is there a way to create a thread but defer it's execution using C++11 without using the operator=

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

two threads are created if i use the following:

```
void func()
{}

std::thread td1;//thread  object created.
...
...
//defer the running of td1 until now
td1 = std::thread(func);//temp thread object(rvalue) created
```

Is there a way to achieve the defer execution but without creating two threads?

Comment: Why does it matter? Do you have a problem with `std::thread::operator=`? It's not like creating a `thread` instance actually creates a thread of execution.

Comment: Defer both creating the object and starting the thread until later, i.e. remove the first line and replace the second one with `thread t1(func);`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the point is, but...

No `operator=`, though two threads are constructed:

```
std::thread td1;
...
std::thread(func).swap(td1);
```

Or no `operator=` and only one thread constructed:

```
std::promise<void> p;
std::thread td1([&]() {
   p.get_future().wait();
   func();
});
...
p.set_value();

td1.join(); // Can't let p go out of scope pending the thread.
```

Maybe what you really want is:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> td1;
...
td1.reset(new std::thread(func));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::thread td1;
```

That creates a thread object, but it **does not** create a thread. So:

```
std::thread td1;
td1 = std::thread(func);
```

is perfectly fine code even if you are concerned about performance.